# Zelix KlassMaster "Class not found"

Tags: java, jar, obfuscation

I'm using [`Zelix KlassMaster`](http://www.zelix.com/klassmaster/download1.html) version 8.0.2 to obfuscate a `JAR` file. The `JAR` itself works fine but when I try to obfuscate it, `Zelix` says that a class has not been found:

```
Error while opening classes. : 'javax.annotation.Nullable' not found. Cannot proceed to next step. Please adjust your Zelix KlassMaster classpath or class file selections.
```

[image]

If I find the said JAR file e.g. [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsr305139jar.htm) and add it to the classpath, another class is not found. This keeps going on and on even though these classes/libraries are never needed or used by my application (which uses some 3rd party libraries obviously).

How do I fix this? I just want to obfuscate my `JAR` file without selecting additional nonsense external JAR files because no necessary classes are actually missing.

Comment: Can you pinpoint what is using those nullable annotations? If it's part of a library and those specific classes aren't used anywhere else you can remove classes by deleting them with a program like 7-zip. It's a cheaty hack but it will work.

Comment: @DankVader:
I think that I can't easily spot the class with nullable annotations because those libraries are huge. Also it's not a good solution for automated build processes and it's definitely not the only occurrence of the "class not found" issue. I'm using another obfuscator now though

Comment: What specific features are you looking for?

Comment: @DankVader:
Not being forced to supply missing classes when they are irrelevant

Comment: I have an idea. How about you provide the extra classes and remove them afterwords? If your program contains a manifest jar pointing to the main class I recently made a program that can automate the task of removing these unused classes. I link to and explain how it works on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507877/minify-code-java/37537322#37537322

Comment: Thanks but it's generally a bad idea to try to automatically minify a `JAR` file due to `reflection` as you probably know

Comment: True. How much does your project rely on reflection and if so how is it used? I'd like to be able to have it not matter if reflection is used and any input would be helpful.

Comment: It doesn't but the underlying 3rd party libraries do quite heavily how it seems

Comment: If you could list the libraries I could figure out how to get started on reflection compatibility.

Comment: `sqlite-jdbc`, `commons-io`, `commons-codec`, `net.lingala.zip4j`, `org.json` and so on. I'm not sure which of them use reflection but some of them do

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza Is your problem solved?

Comment: @Mavie: No, I used a different tool

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza which one, Please tell me. I am also having same problem.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to add all of your projects libraries to the class path as well as the default Java libraries. What you describe happens when you open the project's libraries instead of adding them at the classpath.